Using your iMac as an external monitor for a Windows laptop
I have an iMac Retina 2020 and a Windows ThinkPad laptop. I need to use the iMac's display as an external monitor for the Windows laptop. However, I understand that this is not possible with iMac models released after 2014. Additionally, I cannot install any software on my laptop.
I was considering installing Windows via Boot Camp on my iMac and then connecting it to the laptop via USB-C. I'm not sure if this will work. Can someone help me?

TBH/ external monitors are inexpensive and can solve your problem without resorting to elaborate machinations.  Is there a financial concern about purchasing a monitor? If you use your Thinkpad for your work, can  your employer provide you with a monitor?

Just connecting two computers via USB-C will not magically transfer anything. I‘m not sure there even are software solutions for macOS for this. Get a cheap monitor (or convince your employer to get one for you).

It's not a financial concern. I currently have a third emplyer monitor that I use as an extended display. However, due to space constraints, I need to free up space and eliminate this third monitor. I want to keep my iMac, of course.

Welcome to Ask Different. I had the same need and travel more with an iPad than a Mac. Does your work PC output HDMI? If so, why not use a USB-C HDMI capture card - the ones ompatible with the iPadOS Orion app should work great on your Mac.

I don't think windows or boot camp will do anything but complicate your life since you just need a decent capture card and not the short lived alternate display mode some Intel Mac had and Apple quickly ditched in favor of letting adapters handle video input.

@bmike The canonical answer I linked to might need an update if a UBS-C HDMI capture solution really works.

I will certainly give it a shot - I’m away from my Mac so I want to be 100% sure whether another app besides OBS is ready to receive the input. I am floored at how well Orion works with very inexpensive capture hardware.
